# Faster way to find nearest neighbors with LASlib?

Tags: lidar, c++, nearest-neighbor, optimization

I'm using LASlib to find the nearest neighbors of a subset of points in a point cloud.  I'm using brute force to find nearest neighbors, which is extremely slow (my code below).  Is there a better way, using the LASlib API to find nearest neighbors?

```
LASreadOpener lasreadopener;
lasreadopener.set_file_name("myLasFile.las");
LASreader* lasreader = lasreadopener.open();

float searchDistance = 1.0f;
I64 idx;
while (lasreader->read_point())
{
    //check to see if this point meets my conditions
    if (!conditions_met) // just pseudo code, i acutally check certain point attributes
    {
        continue;
    }

    idx = lasreader->p_count;
    double x = lasreader->point.get_x();
    double y = lasreader->point.get_y();

    // return to beginning
    lasreader->seek(0);

    // loop through all points
    while (lasreader->read_point())
    {
        if (lasreader->point.inside_circle(x, y, searchDistance))
        {
            // do something with this point
        }
    }

    //return to original loop point
    lasreader->seek(idx);
}
lasreader->close();
delete lasreader;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the spatial indexing capability available within LASlib. Here is an example for running a query on *one* point that is known a priori. Note that you need your LAS file to have an accompanying LAX file generated with [LASindex](http://rapidlasso.com/LASindex) for this to be any faster.

```
F64 x = 520450;
F64 y = 2223045; 
F32 searchDistance = 1.0f;
LASreadOpener lasreadopener;
lasreadopener.set_file_name("myLasFile.las");
lasreadopener.set_inside_circle(x, y, searchDistance);

LASreader* lasreader = lasreadopener.open();

while (lasreader->read_point())
{
   // do something with this point
}

lasreader->close();
delete lasreader;
```

Comment: Please do not use your answers to advertise a help site that you appear to be affiliated with.